# Define name i.e. macro as nothing

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

While using a 3rd party shared library i.e. DLL, I have to define the functions usable by their symbol names. So I have to declare some function types.

But the function definition involves a calling convention, in my case `__cdecl`.

So, naturally, this calling convention is only applicable to the MSVC compiler but I still want to compile my portable API abstraction code, which uses boost::dll with linux, even though I can not execute it on my development linux machine, so I can still check the compile time stuff.

So my idea was to define the `__cdecl` name to something as nothing or a white space, a `NOP` if you will, with the pre-processor, but I am not able to do that:

```
#if !BOOST_OS_WINDOWS
#define  __cdecl ( ) /* error, how can I define __cdecl as 'nothing" here? */
#endif

#include <boost/dll/import.hpp>
boost::dll::shared_library lib;

unsigned long device_count(char* pid) {
    typedef unsigned long(__cdecl func_sig)(char *pvid_id);
    return lib.get<func_sig>("DLL_Symbol")(pid);
}
```

Comment: You probably want `#undef` first.

Comment: But it seems more portable to define a `MY_DECL` which results to `__decl` or empty.

Comment: Yeah you re right, will combine that, I guess the good old german idiom of "Den Wald vor lauter Baeumen nicht sehen" applied here.

Comment: (Or, in English, ["not seeing the forest for the trees"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see_the_forest_for_the_trees).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define __cdecl
```

Couldn't be simpler! Or better, to limit the spreading of implementation-reserved identifiers:

```
#if BOOST_OS_WINDOWS
    #define YOURLIB_CDECL __cdecl
#else
    #define YOURLIB_CDECL /* nothing */
#endif
```

Comment: I would be more verbose: `#define __cdecl /* Nothing */`

Comment: *Facepalms self* yeah thanks your right. Hope SO dosn't think I just wanted reputation game here. Consider me: http://giphygifs.s3.amazonaws.com/media/9wQgSJmBhgaRi/giphy.gif

Comment: Actually, it would be much better to use `#ifdev MSVC \n #define CDECL __cdecl \n #else \n #define CDECL /* nothing */ \n #endif` and then use `CDECL` in the actual code.  That way you don't use `__cdecl` (which is a symbol reserved to the implementation in all contexts) in non-MS code.